# How can I record myself playing GameCube games on my computer?

Tags: recording, nintendo-gamecube

I'm wondering specifically for the GameCube, how can I record myself playing.

My TV has two interfaces -- RCA sockets and a coax socket. Standard for most TVs, I guess. I currently connect my GameCube to my TV through the RCA cable, but there is an adapter that goes to the coax socket if I need to do that for some reason.

I was just wondering two things:

- How can I get the image from my GameCube onto my laptop? It has HDMI and VGA inputs if that helps at all.
- How can I record it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a capture card. Most capture cards are pci but there are a few out there that work with usb. You also need software to perform the capture which may or may not be bundled with the card.

Comment: Hmm... you're right. I (naively) believed that I could just plug a cable to one of these ports and do something with it, but all that would do is allow me to use my monitor as a TV screen -- I couldn't record that way. I'll look into some hardware.

Answer (score 0):

[Encore Video Grabber @ Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815153009&cm_re=video_grabber-_-15-153-009-_-Product)  Very cheap Comes with Bundled software and easy to use owned one for over a year.